# django filtering with FormView

Tags: python, django

My goal is to filter objects in ListView. In template i want to have a form, from which objects are filtered. So my form:

```
class ProductFilterForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = ((x, x) for x in range(1, 10))
    width = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

views:

```
class ProductListView(ListView, FormView):
    model = Product
    paginate_by = 16
    template_name = 'product_list.html'
    form_class = ProductFilterForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class
        return context
```

Now form renders in template, nothing more. How can i make it work to filter objects?

Comment: See the docs, they come with examples: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects

Comment: There is no examples of how get data from form and then filter results.